# Find the number of one-one functions $f:\{a,b,c,d\}\to\{0,1,2,3,...,10\}$ such that $2f(a)-f(b)+3f(c)+f(d)=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, permutations, diophantine-equations

Find the number of one-one functions $f:\{a,b,c,d\}\to\{0,1,2,3,...,10\}$ such that $2f(a)-f(b)+3f(c)+f(d)=0$.

My Attempt

I rearranged the equation like this $f(b)=2f(a)+3f(c)+f(d)$.

Now, if $f(c)=0$ then $2f(a)+f(d)\leq 10$

Can the problem be solved by any method other than counting all cases manually. I kept on taking cases and ended up with 31 cases.

The answer given was $31$. Can it be done by some other approach

Comment: Modulo the injectivity requirement, this is equivalent to finding the number of integer points inside a particular convex polytope (in this case, that polytope will be bounded by $x \geq 0, y \geq 0 , z \geq 0, 2x+3y+z \leq 10$). That's a difficult problem, and in this case I believe the only way it can be solved is via enumeration, as might have been done here.